# JavaScript Calculator - scope?

Tags: javascript

I am relatively new to JS, and trying to create a JavaScript calculator that takes a number and then uses the operator with a second number to create a total. Then I could use another operator on that total with another number, and so on, until the clear button is pressed. My biggest problem seems to be with the scope of my variables. At the moment I created a stopgap, that will add and subtract one digit numbers. Is there a reason why this code won't at least multiply and divide single numbers?

My other idea is to create two variables with empty arrays for the two numbers that will be used, so that as each active button is pressed you can push it into the specific array, which I think would solve the problem of only using single digit numbers, right? Thanks in advance! Just trying to learn and keep getting better!

```
// Calculator
var number = '';
var newNumber = '';
var operator = '';
var totalVal = '';
var result = '';
var inputCount = 0;

// Adds clicked numbers to the number variable and then sets value to totalVal
$('.numbers').on('click', function(){
    if(result == ''){
        inputCount++;
        if (inputCount < 2){
            number += $(this).text();
            $('.inner-screen').text(number);
            result = number;
            console.log("number: " + number);
            console.log("result: " + result);
        } else {
            newNumber = $(this).text();
        }
        // number = ''; 
    } else{
        newNumber += $(this).text();
        $('.inner-screen').text(newNumber);
    }
    console.log("number: " + number + ", newNumber: " + newNumber);
});

$('.operators').on('click', function(){
    operator = $(this).text();
    console.log(operator);
    $('.inner-screen').text('');
});

// Resets all the variables when clear button is clicked
$('.clear').on('click', function(){
    number = '';
    result = '';
    newNumber = '';
    operator = '';
    totalVal = '';
    inputCount = 0;
    console.log('Clear Button Worked!');
    $('.inner-screen').text('');
});

$('.eval').on('click', function(){
    console.log("num1: " + number + ", operator: " + operator + ", num2: " + newNumber);
    if (operator === " + "){
        result = parseFloat(newNumber) + parseFloat(number);
        console.log(result);
    } else if (operator === " - "){
        result =  parseFloat(number) - parseFloat(newNumber);
        console.log(totalVal);
    } else if (operator === " X "){
        result = parseFloat(newNumber) * parseFloat(number);
        console.log(result);
    } else if (operator === " / "){
        result = parseFloat(number) / parseFloat(newNumber);
        console.log(result);
    } else {
        console.log("didn't catch");
    }

    $('.inner-screen').text(result);
    number = '';
    newNumber = '';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > Is there a reason why this code won't at least multiply and divide single numbers?

Right-o. I see what's going on.

Once you've pressed eval, you need to remember some state:

```
number = result;
result = '';
newNumber = '';
operator = '';
inputCount = 1;
```

Old version:
http://jsfiddle.net/xjegrp58/

New version, with state added to the eval function:
http://jsfiddle.net/axLhcawf/

Try this on each:
2 * 2 = 4, then * 2 to get 8